# Cómo insertar fórmulas en un input en formato 2^3+1^2?

Tags: html, css, html5

¿Cómo insertar fórmulas en un input en formato 2^3+1^2, garantizando que muestre en HTML la fórmula correctamente?

Lo que encontré antes era para poner en HTML formula como `2^2` se utiliza la etiqueta `2<sub>2</sub>`, pero quisiera ver una manera para poner en un input la fórmula  y no aparecía así `2^2` .

Comment: Mostrar la fórmula en HTML5 podría usar la sintaxis que indicas o [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML). Para hacer eso en un campo `input`, necesitas un editor que procese ese dato como [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax) o algún otro que encuentres y se ajuste a tu proyecto.